# problemas wsgi me muestra el index en el navagador pero cuando quiero ir a otra pagina no me deja

Tags: apache, flask

estoy tratande subir un app web con apache e instale el modulo wsgi pero al parecer no me esta reconociendo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.